# Change template directory in Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I've never found an answer to this question that actually seems to work.

I have combined Laravel with a WordPress installation. Everything works, but WordPress is still referring to it's default template folder. I would like the templates to come from the Laravel views folder, so I can use the Blade template engine as I always have done in my normal Laravel projects.

So far I have used add_filter functions with different filters and for one reason or another can get nothing that affects the template dropdown you see when editing pages. It's particularly important as it affects the Advanced Custom Fields that I want to appear on certain pages using certain templates.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [Laraish](https://github.com/laraish/laraish), a WodPress theme that based on Laravel. Works seamlessly with ACF too :)